# Change the direction value on the change of the language in mui, nextjs and i18n

Tags: next.js, material-ui, i18next

I am working on a new project and I've used mui along with nextjs and i18n for localization. The thing is, I would like to add come styling in case the language changes from English (ltr) to Arabic (rtl) but I can't find a proper way to do it. I've tried to change the direction property inside the mui theme as following:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  direction: i18n.dir(),
  breakpoints: {
     values: {
        xs: 0,
        sm: 700,
        md: 1024,
        lg: 1200,
        xl: 1536,
  },
},
```

but the value never changes in the theme although I've checked the dir() inside i18n and it did work. The other approach that I've tried is, using :dir/:lang selectors inside the stylesheet but it didn't work at all.

Has anyone got any suggestions on this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the i18n localization to your app

use the useEffect hook from react inside the functional component as

```
const [locale, setLocale] = useState(i18n.language);
i18n.on("languageChanged", (lng) => setLocale(i18n.language));

const currentLangObj = languages.find((lang) => lang.code === locale);

useEffect(() => {
    document.body.dir = currentLangObj.dir || "ltr";
}, [currentLangObj]);
```

Here we need to build an array of languages which will container the language code as well as the direction

then find the lang with same code which we have in our locale and set he document.body.dir to it or by default to ltr

for more info you can visit https://blog.logrocket.com/react-localization-with-i18next/